# WCF Message Version

Tags: wcf

We have two WCF services.  One is a service (A) with a method on it that is used to send data to it (push).  The second is a service (B) that sends data to A.  When i send data to A from B i get this error.  Does anyone know what this might mean?

> The message version of the outgoing message (Soap12
>   (http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope) AddressingNone
>   (http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none)) does not
>   match that of the encoder (Soap12
>   (http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope) Addressing10
>   (http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing)). Make sure the binding is
>   configured with the same version as the message.

Comment: It would be very beneficial to understand your WCF configuration. Can you supply the client configuration service A uses to push information and the configuration for the endpoint and service B exposes?

Comment: _"Does anyone know what this might mean?"_ - what it means is spelled out exactly in the error message. Perhaps you mean to ask another question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error loosely means "the encoder expected to write one kind of message, but the binding gave it a different kind".

In your specific case, you seem to have matching SOAP versions (which is required), but your message encoding is set up with `AddressingNone` where your binding is set up with `Addressing10`; the binding is putting an address on the message, but the encoder can't deal with it.

You need to either identify the component which is setting the addressing on the message (it may be the binding you're using) or reconfigure your message encoding to expect the addressing element.